# When is the computational cost of applying a function convex?

Tags: python, pandas, computation

It seems that a lot of stuff I do in Pandas has convex computational-time costs in the amount of data I have (e.g.  1 row takes 1 second, 2 rows takes 2.2 seconds, 4 rows takes 6 seconds, etc.).

Why are computational costs not linearly increasing the the amount of data I have?  For example, this function I wrote:

```
def fractrips1brand(trip): 
    # Get number of transaction rows for THIS sepcific consumer
    art = trip[trip.Item_Id.isin(insidegood)].Item_Id.nunique()
    output = pd.Series({'numinsidegoods': art })
    return output


gr_TILPS = TILPStemp.groupby('uniqueid')
output = gr_TILPS.apply(fractrips1brand)
```

Seems to exhibit such costs.

Why is it not `O(n)`?

Comment: Could I have a runnable example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common for functions to have greater-than-linear time complexity.
Sorting, for example, has `O(n log n)` complexity.

```
gr_TILPS = TILPStemp.groupby('uniqueid')
```

`groupby` [sorts the keys by default](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), so this call has at least `O(n log n)` complexity. You can turn the sorting  off by using

```
gr_TILPS = TILPStemp.groupby('uniqueid', sort=False)
```

---

In Pandas 0.15 and older versions, `Series.nunique` [(source)](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L429) calls `Series.value_counts` [(source)](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py#L371) which also sorts the values by default. So this is another function call with O(n log n) complexity. Since this one occurs in `fractrips1brand`, the total complexity of `gr_TILPS.apply(fractrips1brand)` is at least `O(m n log n)` where `m` is the number of groups.

Update: In the next release of Pandas (version 0.16.0) `Series.nunique` [should be significantly faster](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/9134).

Comment: I think we have different definitions of convex.  What is something that grows faster than linear that is not convex?  Convex doesnt just mean quadratic.  Suppose C(x) is the computational time function for x rows. By convexity I just mean C'(x)>0 , C''(x)>0

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was thinking of concave not convex. Still, there is nothing unusual about a faster-than-linear time complexity. Sorting is `O(n log n)` for example.

Comment: Great, the computational complexity is a great thing to know to predict how long my full dataset will take to execute.  Why exactly is it O(n log n)?  I guess my question is what is the intuition for why the above function, for example, wouldn't be O(n)?

Comment: `value_counts` seems a strange choice in nunique, `Series.unique()` doesn't sort, so you could just call len on that (in O(n))?

Comment: @Andy: I agree that `nunique` doesn't need to sort.